# MS CRM2013 JavaScript option issue

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I use in CRM 2011 this code

```
    var option = optionset.OptionSet.Options[i];
    var oValue = option.Value;
```

But it not work in CRM2013.
How I can refactor it?

Answer (score 4):

To get value or label of the option set field use below code

```
var optionsetAttr = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("fieldname");   
var text = optionsetAttr.getText();
var value = optionsetAttr.getValue();
```

To iterate through options of option set field use below

```
var optionsetAttr = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("fieldname");
for(var i=0; optionsetAttr.getOptions().length; i++){
       alert(optionsetAttr.getOptions()[i].text);
       alert(optionsetAttr.getOptions()[i].value);
   }
```

Replace the "fieldname" with your field name, of course.